# Delete row from DIV table when button clicked

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the following divTable:

```html
<div class="divTable">
        <div class="divTableBody">
                <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell">TagName</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">Higher/Lower</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">Threshold</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">Delete Alert?</div>
                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow" *ngFor="let com of currentAlerts">
                        <div class="divTableCell">{{com.tagname}}</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">{{com.symbol == 1 ? 'Higher than' : 'Lower than'}}</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">{{com.threshold}}</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">
                           <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" (click)="submit(com.ID)">
                              Delete
                           </button>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

As you can see this table loops through the array `currentAlerts` and creates a row for each item found.

The array is popuplated within `ngOnInit()` by connecting to a web API.

```js
this.alerts.getCurrentAlerts(this.loginEmail)
      .subscribe
      ((data: CurrentAlerts[]) => {this.currentAlerts = data;
        console.log(this.currentAlerts.length)
        if(!this.currentAlerts || !this.currentAlerts.length){
          this.alertsTitleMessage = "You have no alerts configured."
        }else{
          this.alertsTitleMessage = "Here are the Alerts you have set up "
        }}
      );
```

When the Delete button is clicked the a delete request is sent to the database.

```js
  submit(ID){
    let isDeleted = null;
    this.alerts.deleteCurrentAlert(ID).subscribe(result => isDeleted = result);
    this.manageCurrentAlerts();
    
  }
```

All the above works as expected and the data is deleted from the database.

## Question

How do I get the table to remove the deleted row?  I have read answers that state to delete the row from the arra using `splice` but I couldnt get that working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add `index` in `ngFor`, `*ngFor="let com of currentAlerts;let i = index"`
- In delete button, pass `index` i.e `i` instead of `com.ID`
- Use `splice` in TS function, `this.currentAlerts.splice(index,1)`

Try like this:

```
<div class="divTableRow" *ngFor="let com of currentAlerts;let i = index">
  ...
  <div class="divTableCell">
    <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" (click)="submit(i)">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
submit(index){
  this.currentAlerts.splice(index,1)
  ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After deletion from database delete it from array.

```
submit(ID){
    let isDeleted = null;
    this.alerts.deleteCurrentAlert(ID).subscribe(result => isDeleted = result);
    this.manageCurrentAlerts();
    for(var i = 0; i< this.currentAlerts.length ; i++) {
     if(this.currentAlerts[i].ID === ID) {
       this.currentAlerts.splice(i, 1);
     }
    }    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your response from the server you need to delete the item from the array so in your method: 
`this.alerts.deleteCurrentAlert(ID).subscribe(result => isDeleted = result);`

you should apply the filter method. Splice could work too but Filter has better performance.

Your method should look like this :

```
this.alerts.deleteCurrentAlert(ID).subscribe(result => {
  this.currentAlerts = this.currentAlerts.filter(item => item.ID != ID);
  isDeleted = result;
});
```